# How do I find out what services are bound to a port number?

Tags: macos, unix, port

Given a TCP/UDP port number, how do I find out the name of the service bound to that port?

I want to do this on various flavours of Unix. Mostly Gnu/Linux (usually Debian) and Mac OS X.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Various UNIX. Mostly Gnu/Linux (usually Debian) & Mac OS X.

Comment: You might want to think about rewording your question. Asking for tools/software is off-topic. If you can change the question to something like "How do I do xyz" it will be better ...

Comment: @DavidPostill You're right, it's pretty rough; I was a bit sleep deprived and in a rush at the time. If you'd like to make some changes, you're more than welcome to.

Comment: I've made some edits to your question so it doesn't look like you are asking for a tool/software recoomendation. Please review the edits to make sure that your question is still the same question you wanted to ask.

Comment: @DavidPostill I'm sure it's fine. Full disclosure (just to be clear & perfectly honest) though; I *was* looking for a tool recommendation.

Comment: This way you *might* get one recommended in an answer. With the old wording it would probably have have been closed as off topic.

Comment: Your original question said "Basically; I'm looking for a tool" - that makes it immediately off topic regardless of what the rest of question is. Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). We have http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ for that but please first read [What is required for a question to contain “enough information”](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) before asking over there.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux that's

```
ss -lntp
ss -lnup
```

for TCP and UDP, respectively. `l` stands for listening, `p` returns the process number that's listening on the port, and `n` is my pet peeve, it does not convert IP addresses into names.

On Mac OS you may use the following command, which also works on Linux:

```
lsof -n -i4TCP:$PORT | grep LISTEN
```

i4 specifies that you are using IPv4, the rest should be self-explanatory.

You can also use (on Linux)

```
netstat -pntl | grep $PORT
```

but netstat is by now obsolete, or

```
fuser -n tcp $PORT
```

which is not. That's as far as I go.