# Find source of outgoing traffic

Tags: linux, ubuntu, webserver, malware

My Ubuntu web server has been infected by a bot that is brute-force attacking Wordpress sites.

I can see the outgoing POST requests and their content, but I am not able to find the script, pid or user that are generating these requests. Of course my goal is to remove that malicious software.

Do you know any way to find where is that outgoing traffic being generated?

Comment: Often these infections employ rootkit techniques to hide themselves. Have you tried running `chkrootkit` or `rkhunter` on your machine?

Comment: Also, you may want to read the first part of this answer: http://superuser.com/questions/977445/how-do-i-find-out-what-services-are-bound-to-a-port-number/977451#977451

Comment: Thanks @MariusMatutiae that link helped me, the command which tells you the PID/Program name for a connection is `netstat -npt`, though it seems that as you said they are hiding themselves

Comment: The modern command to find out which process is listening on which TCP port is actually `ss -lntp`;  normally, nowadays, `netstat` is just a wrapper for `ss` to maintain compatibility of older software.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nethogs`, e.g.:

```
nethogs eth0
```

Should show you how much traffic is going from given process.